# C++11 overloaded methods with forwarding to a unique method

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following class in c++11:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

void overloaded_function(const std::string& param) {
  someStuffHere
}
void overloaded_function(std::string&& param) {
  someStuffHere
}
```

As you can see the overloaded_function implementation is exactly the same. I would like to create a new function instead of having the same implementation into two different methods. I tried with:

```
void overloaded_function(const std::string& param) {
  uniqueCall(std::forward<std::string&>(param));
}
void overloaded_function(std::string&& param) {
  uniqueCall(std::forward<std::string&&>(param));
}
void uniqueCall(T&& param) {
    someStuffHere
}
```

but it doesn't work due to the lvalue reference not accepted by uniqueCall.

Comment: Should be a template.

Comment: Why the need for a non-const lvalue reference? Do you modify the argument?

Comment: @StoryTeller sorry, added const to lvalue reference, no need to modify it

Comment: That sort of changes the whole question...

Comment: @Galik It was my fault, sorry. Let me know how it changes :)

Comment: I don't mean to offend you, but you seem to be engaged in cargo-cult programming here. You may have valid reasons to do this, but the question does not express them.

Comment: @StoryTeller No offense, I'm a c++11 noob, I'm here to learn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once r-value parameter gets a name - it can be treated, this named parameter, as  l-value reference, as you can read in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category:

> Even if the variable's type is
>   rvalue reference, the expression consisting of its name is an lvalue
>   expression;

So you might write as simple as this:

```
void overloaded_function(std::string& param) {
  someStuffHere
}
void overloaded_function(std::string&& param) {
  overloaded_function(param); // here param type is std::string&
}
```

If you really enjoy to have "common" function - it shall accept lvalue ref for the very same reasons:

```
void uniqueCall(std::string& param) {
  some stuff here
}
void overloaded_function(std::string& param) {
  uniqueCall(param)
}
void overloaded_function(std::string&& param) {
  uniqueCall(param); // here param type is std::string&
}
```

Comment: I'm a nitpicker, I know, but it's still an r-value reference. Just so happens that an r-value reference is itself an l-value.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, it is. But this is not like const_cast - I can do whatever l-value allows me to do with it - so IMO nothing wrong with such approach.

Comment: What does const_cast have to do with it? You made a mistake in terminology. The reference you quote actually has it right.

Comment: @StoryTeller - I wrote it too shortly. If you have const reference - it might point to real const value (meaning cannot modify) - with const_cast you might do lvalue reference from it - and might attempt to modify - what is UB.  In this case - referring by the lvalue reference is safe. I just try to understand if anything can go wrong here

Comment: StoryTeller is referring to the fact that you are saying "once r-value parameter gets a name - it is l-value reference" which is just plainly wrong. It is still an rvalue ref, the only difference is that now you have an lvalue, `param` that you can pass to the other function.

Comment: @Rakete1111 - ok I changed the wording of my answer, I hope now it is both - very strict and still understandable. But - I really want to know if there is any practical implication of this subtle difference? I mean both references in this example refer to the same object, isn't that true?

Comment: @Piotr Yes it is, just as you can't say that a pointer just became a pointer to pointer or something.

Comment: @Rakete1111 are you able to show this diffrence in example? Look here - https://wandbox.org/permlink/zZcQvuMSId1RqNZD  - it works as expected.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't need to modify the argument, you don't *need* an rvalue overload at all<sup>1</sup>. A const lvalue reference will happily bind to an rvalue.

That's how C++ always worked, and rvalue references don't change that.

So a simple

```
void overloaded_function(const std::string& param) {
  //someStuffHere
}
```

Will bind to an argument of whatever value category.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> - And if you did need to modify it, then passing rvalues is a bit dubious.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

A common pattern is to have the argument type of the interface function deduced:

```
template<class Param>
void overloaded_function(Param&& param)
{
    commonStuff(param);
    mutabilityDependentStuff(std::forward<Param>(param));    
}
```

Regardless of whether Param is an r-value or l-value reference, it can decay into a const l-value reference:

```
void commonStuff(std::string const& arg)
{
    //
}
```

And `std::forward<>` can use used to detect proper decay into mutable and immutable versions (mutable r-values will decay to mutable l-values):

```
void mutabilityDependentStuff(std::string const& arg)
{
    //
}

void mutabilityDependentStuff(std::string& arg)
{
    //
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest delegating directly to a template function:

```
void overloaded_function(const std::string& param) {
  uniqueCall(param);
}
void overloaded_function(std::string&& param) {
  uniqueCall(std::move(param));
}
template <class T>
void uniqueCall(T&& param) {
    someStuffHere
}
```

If you identify some substantial enough amount off work not benefitting from treating `param` as anything but a `const std::string&`, it *might* make sense for executable-size or organization to promote it to its own function. Maybe it makes sense to treat it as a C++17 `std::string_view` for that?

That template-function you delegate to, or the helper-function you call from it, might even be some interesting and valuable addition to your interface, maybe after a minor adjustment, see `.emplace_@()` and `.put_@()` in the standard-library containers.